# Tamron 24-70mm F/2.8 battery drain issues

Tags: canon, tamron, battery-drain, electronics

Ok, this is a bit of a strange thing. Bear with me  please.

The camera is a Canon 6D and the lens is a Tamron 24-70mm F/2.8 VC (first generation, not the G2). When I have this lens on my camera and put a 100% full battery inside and not use the camera for two days, the battery will be completely empty.

I have looked around a bit and apparently several people report this. Some say this only happens with low serial numbers, but some also reported the same issue with newer ones. Some people said turning VC off fixed the issue for them, and well, it's weird.

Turning VC off did seem to fix it at first, but after 2 days of the battery being still full (no use at all of the camera!), the third day it suddenly dropped to 40% again.

Always taking out the battery is kinda not ideal. What could cause this, and is there a way for me to fix this? I'd be happy if just turning off VC would "fix" it, but that seems to be hit and miss too.

I understand that many electronic devices aren't fully off when they are "off", but I fail to see what could cause this rather significant drain, sometimes it drains up to 4% per hour being "off".

Is there anything I can do besides sending it in to Tamron for repair or replacement?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a known problem between the lens and some recent Canon bodies:

- Flickr: [Tamron 24-70 drains my battery](https://www.flickr.com/groups/1878558@N24/discuss/72157632303742096/)

Someone in that discussion says that Tamron has a fix, so get in touch with Tamron service.